What is the correct syntax to filter JSON objects by value of key in Redis Insights?
I have an instance of Redis containing JSON objects.
Example of JSON object:
{
  ...
  description: ""
  metaPublishedOnDiscord: true
  metaIsHot: false
}

I have also an index for these objects called NewsArticles:index.
From redis insights, I want to find all JSON objects containing metaPublishedOnDiscord: false

From in the attached image I am trying to find all objects that have the boolean metaPublishedOnDiscord set to true. @metaPublishedOnDiscord:true on NewsArticle:index doesn't work. What is  the correct syntax?
//edit:
I created the index using legacy redis-om api.
const Connection = require('./Connection');
const { Schema, Entity } = require('redis-om');

class NewsArticle extends Entity {};

const newsArticleSchema = new Schema(NewsArticle, {
    url: { type: 'string' }, 
    img: { type: 'string' }, 
    title: { type: 'text' },
    description: { type: 'text' },
    content: { type: 'text' },
    tags: { type: 'string[]' },
    cityId: { type: 'string' },
    metaScrapedAtTimestamp: { type: 'date' },
    metaPublishedOnDiscord: { type: 'boolean' },
    metaIsHot: { type: 'boolean' }
});

module.exports = Connection.start().then(c => {
    const newsArticleRepository = c.fetchRepository(newsArticleSchema);
    newsArticleRepository.createIndex();
    return newsArticleRepository;
});

If it helps, the type of the index is STRING, while the type of the indexed object is JSON.


Could you update the question to include how you created your index? The type of the field (i.e. TAG, TEXT, NUMERIC) you are searching on matters for the query.

I create the index programmatically via a legacy version of node-redis-om :)!

Excellent. I wrote Redis OM for Node.js so I can certainly answer this. ;)

Looks like you figured it out!

@GuyRoyse yup, I know. You're famous! I was quite happy when you answered! See you and thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

I've found an answer. The correct way is to use this kind of syntax:
@metaPublishedOnDiscord:{false}

My problem is that i have been missing {} wrapping the value.
